# Operate numbers with bash_rematch regex groups

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I need to parse the ouput of a comand and treat the numbers to convert them to Kilobytes if they are not.

**Output from system:**

```
5.1g Service
227292 Xorg
218284 gnome-shell
```

With the command I'm using is not possible to get all the results with the same type (Kilboytes). I need to check if the data from Service is in GB or Kilobytes and make the conversion.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Variables
comand=`top -b -o RES -n 1 | awk '{print $6,$NF}'| grep $1`

#Regex
regexGB="([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]+))*g"
regexKB="([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)"
regexdigit=".*[0-9]"

if [[ $comand =~ $regexGB ]];then
        echo "Digit is in GB"
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[*]}"

        i=1
        n=${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
        while [[ $i -lt $n ]]
        do
            echo "  capture[$i]: ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
            let i++
        done

elif [[ $comand =~ $regexKB ]];then
        echo "Digit is in KB"
else
        echo "Printing Output $1. Comand: $comand"
fi
```

**Result:**

```
Digit is in GB
5.1g 5 .1 1
  capture[1]: 5
  capture[2]: .1
  capture[3]: 1
```

I tried multiplying the ${BASH_REMATCH[$i] * 1024 but it's not working.
How could I convert only the number in gigabytes to Kilobytes?

Comment: I don't see any multiplication in your code, but `$((${BASH_REMATCH[$i] * 1024))` should do. Please add the multiplication statement to your code. BTW, why are you setting the variable `regexdigit`, if you never use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to avoid reading the command output twice.  A compound `if` can capture the output that will need to be evaluated and converted (potentially) to kilobytes. Use bash parameter expansion and [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the trailing 'g' from the gigabytes output and then transform to kilobytes.

```
#!/bin/bash

re_gb="([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]+))g"
re_kb="([0-9]+)"

while read -r line ; do
  if [[ $line =~ $re_gb || $line =~ $re_kb ]] ; then
    if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} == *g ]] ; then
        # remove the trailing 'g' from the gigabytes regex capture group
        num=${BASH_REMATCH[0]//g/}i

        # use bc for converting to kilobytes as
        # bash cannot perform multiplication on floats. 
        # Dividing by one removes the float. 
        # Remove the divide by one for decimal output.
        bc <<<"$num * 1024 * 1024 / 1"
    else
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    fi
  fi
done < <(top -b -o RES -n 1 | awk '{print $6,$NF}'| grep $1)
```

Using the output sample from your command:

```
5.1g Service
227292 Xorg
218284 gnome-shell
```

The script output would be:

```
$ ./script
5347737
227292
```

218284